# TYPO3 Fluid add date now to URL

Tags: date, url, typo3, fluid

I know how to add the data to a URL in PHP, but now this is TYPO3 with Fluid.
I need to add date now to an URL like

```
http://domain.dk/form.html?tx_powermail_pi1[field][30]=DATENOW
```

But how can i do this in TYPO3+FLUID ?

**ADD / EDIT 19/05/2014..**

Im trying to use the time as an booking id.

Okay so I have the folder /www/typo3conf/ext/powermail/Classes/ViewHelpers

In that folder I have a file called BookIdViewHelper.php with this code

```
     <?php
#Booking ID
class BookIdViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
     * Renders time()
     *
     * @return int The current timestamp
     */
    public function render() {
        return time();
    }
}
```

And then i have the link with

```
<a href="http://www.domain.dk/?id=47&tx_powermail_pi1[field][30]={urs:time()}">
```

And then I in the template /www/typo3conf/ext/powermail/Resources/Private/Templates/Forms
in the form.html file i added the namespace like this.

```
{namespace vh=Tx_Powermail_ViewHelpers}
{namespace urs=Tx_Powermail_ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Default" />

Render Powermail Form
{forms}             All Forms with their Pages and their Fields


<f:section name="main">

    <f:flashMessages class="powermail_message powermail_message_error" />

    <f:if condition="{forms}">
        <f:then>
            <f:for each="{forms}" as="form">
                <f:form
                        action="{action}"
                        controller="Forms"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data"
                        class="powermail_form powermail_form_{form.uid} {form.css} {vh:Misc.MorestepClass(activate: '{settings.main.moresteps}', class: 'powermail_morestep')}">
                    <h3>{form.title} - {urs.time()}</h3>
                    <f:render partial="FormError" arguments="{error}" />

                    <f:for each="{form.pages}" as="page">
                        <fieldset class="powermail_fieldset powermail_fieldset_{page.uid} {page.css}">
                            <legend class="powermail_legend">{page.title}</legend>
                            <f:for each="{page.fields}" as="field">
                                <f:render partial="Forms/{vh:String.Upper(string: '{field.type}')}" arguments="{field: field}" />
                            </f:for>
                        </fieldset>
                    </f:for>

                    <f:form.hidden name="form" value="{form.uid}" />
                    <f:render partial="HoneyPod" arguments="{form: form}" />
                </f:form>
            </f:for>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:translate key="error_no_form" />
        </f:else>
    </f:if>

</f:section>
```

But its not working.. im only getting the text {urs:time()}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the f:format.date viewhelper to output the date in a given format like shown below:

```
<a href="http://domain.dk/form.html?tx_powermail_pi1[field][30]={f:format.date(date: '', format: 'd.m.Y')}">Link</a>
```

The f:format.date viewhelper outputs the current date if the parameter date is empty (not null).

If your field (in this case a powermail field) requires a timestamp, I would recommend to  create an own viewhelper, which outputs the current timestamp like shown below.

```
class TimeViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
     * Renders time()
     *
     * @return int The current timestamp
     */
    public function render() {
        return time();
    }

}
```

Usage would the be like:

```
<a href="http://domain.dk/form.html?tx_powermail_pi1[field][30]={yournamespace:time()}">Link</a>
```

Comment: Okay do I save that in the main template or.. and then add namespace TYPO3\Urs\ViewHelpers; just over the class... and then call it with Urs:time() ?

Comment: The new ViewHelper could be part of an extension and you should save the PHP code in extension-root\Classes\ViewHelpers\TimeViewhelper.php. Then you can bind the new Viewhelper with {namespace urs=VENDOR\ExtKey\ViewHelpers} and use urs:time()

Comment: im almost there DerHansen plz. see my ADD.

Comment: The classname of the Viewhelper cannot contain spaces. Use "BookIdViewHelper". Then in your Fluid template add "{namespace urs=TYPO3\BookId\ViewHelpers}" and then use "{urs:time()}" to get the time. If you put the viewhelper directly in the powermail extension viewhelpers, then you should use "{namespace: urs=Tx_Powermail_ViewHelpers}". Remember that the viewhelper gets overwritten when you update powermail.

Comment: Hi derhansen plz. see my add/Edit in main question.

Comment: Since you have placed the new ViewHelper directly in the Powermail VievHelpers, you can access it through the Powermail namespace. Also your ViewHelper is called "BookId" and not time, since the name of he ViewHelper is extracted from the classname/filename. So in this case, you should call {vh:bookId()} or {vh:bookid()} to get the output of your ViewHelper